# xna 4.0 animation looping

Tags: animation, loops, xna-4.0

Hello everyone I have been following this tutorial here http://www.gogo-robot.com/2011/05/30/xna-skinned-model-animations/ and so far its great got the animations playing and everything, but now I want to expand it and stop the continuous loops say for instance i press the a key to make the model jump when  i release the a key i want him to stop jumping but if i hold the a key i want him to keep jumping. Here what i have tried so far
and none of it works.
I am stumped here on how to do this thanks for any help with this.

```
 private void HandleInput(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        currentGamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

        // Check for changing anims
        //SkinningData skinningData = model.Tag as SkinningData;
        SkinningData sd = jumper.model.Tag as SkinningData;

        if (currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (jumper.animationPlayer.CurrentClip.Name != "Fire")
                jumper.animationPlayer.StartClip(sd.AnimationClips["Fire"]);
        }


        if (currentGamePadState.Buttons.X == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (jumper.animationPlayer.CurrentClip.Name != "DieF")
                jumper.animationPlayer.StartClip(sd.AnimationClips["DieF"]);

        }

        //does not work
        if (currentGamePadState.Buttons.X == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            if (jumper.animationPlayer.CurrentClip.Name == "DieF")
                jumper.animationPlayer.StartClip(sd.AnimationClips["Idel"]);

        }


        if (currentGamePadState.Buttons.Y == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (jumper.animationPlayer.CurrentClip.Name != "Idel")
                jumper.animationPlayer.StartClip(sd.AnimationClips["Idle"]);
        }

        //does not work
        if (jumper.animationPlayer.CurrentTime ==    jumper.animationPlayer.CurrentClip.Duration)
        {
            //set him back to idel
            jumper.animationPlayer.StartClip(sd.AnimationClips["Idle"]);

        }
```

I have tried these configuration with no luck in the game

```
        // Starts playing the entirety of the given clip
    public void StartClip(string clip, bool loop)
    {
        AnimationClip clipVal = skinningData.AnimationClips[clip];
        StartClip(clip, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), clipVal.Duration, loop);
    }

    // Plays a specific portion of the given clip, from one frame
    // index to another
    public void StartClip(string clip, int startFrame, int endFrame, bool loop)
    {
        AnimationClip clipVal = skinningData.AnimationClips[clip];

        StartClip(clip, clipVal.Keyframes[startFrame].Time,
            clipVal.Keyframes[endFrame].Time, loop);
    }

    // Plays a specific portion of the given clip, from one time
    // to another
    public void StartClip(string clip, TimeSpan StartTime, TimeSpan EndTime, bool loop)
    {
        CurrentClip = skinningData.AnimationClips[clip];
        currentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        currentKeyframe = 0;
        Done = false;
        this.startTime = StartTime;
        this.endTime = EndTime;
        this.loop = loop;

        // Copy the bind pose to the bone transforms array to reset the animation
        skinningData.BindPose.CopyTo(BoneTransforms, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not attach a bool on the animation clip to tell it to play only once, or an *active* variable that can be called.

Comment: Where would you put the loop or active variable in the game I really dont know I tried to do the loop control in the AnimationClip class but that did not work had the same effect as before but it played just one or two frames from the animation then frezes

Comment: Taking a quick look at the link you posted, found this:

`// If we reached the end, loop back to the start.
                bool hasLooped = false;
                while (time >= currentClipValue.Duration)
                {
                    hasLooped = true;
                    time -= currentClipValue.Duration;
                }
 
                // If we've looped, reprocess the events
                if (hasLooped)
                {
                    CheckEvents(ref time, ref lastTime);
                }
            }`
Its in the updateBoneTransforms function of your animationPlayer

Comment: Yes i noticed that but haven't the foggiest on what to do with it. I tried just commenting that out and that and also this  // If we reached the end, loop back to the start.
                bool hasLooped = false;
                while (time >= currentClipValue.Duration)
                {
                    hasLooped = false;
                    //hasLooped = true;
                    time -= currentClipValue.Duration;
                }

               and the animations still looped

Comment: have you tried attaching an ELSE IF at the end of each if statement to tell it to not play if you are not pressing the button? 

`if (currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (jumper.animationPlayer.CurrentClip.Name != "Fire")
                jumper.animationPlayer.StartClip(sd.AnimationClips["Fire"]);
        }`  

you could even put an idle animation clip in the else if.

Comment: I tried something like that and it worked for just one animation fine then I put in another one and it froze up the game. I have been messing with the animationPlayer and this seams to be working to a degree have not tested it fully but its stoping two different animations

Comment: if (Loop)
                {
                    // If we reached the end, loop back to the start.    
                    while (time >= currentClipValue.Duration)
                        time -= currentClipValue.Duration;
                    //CheckEvents(ref time, ref lastTime);
                }
                else if (time > currentClipValue.Duration)
                {
                    // Clamp at end anim 
                    time = currentClipValue.Duration;
                }